# Debug Error r6010 Abort Has Been Called in C++

Tags: c++, debugging, abort

I have just received this error for the first time and I'm not so sure what it means.

It's my first time playing with try/catch. I know my formatting is very messy, I'll keep in mind to organize it next time!

=======DRIVER========

```
 #include "trashcan.h"
 #include <iostream> 
 using namespace std;


int main( ) {
cout << "Welcome to TrashCan Program!" << endl;
TrashCan myCan;
TrashCan yourCan;
TrashCan nothing;

yourCan.setSize( 12 );
myCan.setSize( 12 );
nothing.setSize ( 0 );

yourCan.addItem( );
yourCan.addItem( );


myCan.addItem( );








myCan.printCan();
yourCan.printCan();

TrashCan combined = yourCan + myCan;
  cout << "this can's filled to " << combined.getContents( ) << endl;

TrashCan other = combined - myCan;
  cout << "the other can's filled to " << other.getContents( ) << endl;

if (combined > other) {
cout << "looks like combined is bigger..." << endl;
}
else {
cout << "looks like other is bigger..." << endl;
}
if (myCan > other) {
cout << "looks like myCan is bigger..." << endl;
}
else {
cout << "looks like other is bigger..." << endl;
}
if (yourCan < myCan) {
cout << "looks like yourCan is smaller..." << endl;
}
else {
cout << "looks like myCan is smaller..." << endl;
}

// let's throw some exceptions...

try {
TrashCan empty = empty - combined;
cout << "something not right here..." << endl;
} catch( std::logic_error ) {
// an exception should get thrown... 
// so the lines of code here should
// be run, not the cout statement above...
cout << "exception was caught.  moving on..." << endl;
}

try {
nothing.addItem( );
cout << "something not right here..." << endl;
} catch( std::logic_error ) {
// an exception should get thrown... 
// so the lines of code here should
// be run, not the cout statement above...
cout << "exception was caught.  moving on..." << endl;

}


return( 0 );
}
```

=====trashcan.cpp========

```
#include "trashcan.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;



TrashCan::TrashCan( ) {
myIsCovered = false;
my_Size = 0;
my_Contents = 0;
my_Empty = 0;
}

TrashCan::TrashCan( int size ) {
myIsCovered = false;
my_Size = size;
my_Contents = 0;
my_Empty = 0;
}

TrashCan::TrashCan( int size, int contents, int empty ) {
myIsCovered = false;
my_Size = size;
my_Contents = contents;
my_Empty = empty;
}

void TrashCan::setSize( int size ) {
if (size < 0 ){
    throw logic_error("exception was caught.  moving on...");
}
else{
my_Size = size;
}
}

int TrashCan::getSize( ) {
return( my_Size );

}

int TrashCan::getContents( ) {
return( my_Contents );
}

void TrashCan::addItem( ) {
my_Contents = my_Contents + 1;
if (my_Contents > my_Size || my_Contents < my_Size){
    throw logic_error("exception was caught.  moving on...");
}
}

void TrashCan::empties( ) {
my_Contents = 0;
}

void TrashCan::cover( ) {
myIsCovered = true;
}

void TrashCan::uncover( ) {
myIsCovered = false;
}

void TrashCan::printCan( ) {
cout << "A TrashCan with a size=" << my_Size << " and containing " <<                     my_Contents << " piece";
if (my_Contents != 1) {
    cout << "s";
}
cout << " of trash" << endl;
}

TrashCan operator+ ( const TrashCan& yourCan, const TrashCan& myCan ) {             /* This is where I override the + and - operators... I put in the error messages     for over filling and under filling the trashcan */

    TrashCan combined;
combined.my_Contents = yourCan.my_Contents + myCan.my_Contents ;


    return( combined );

}

TrashCan operator- ( const TrashCan& combined, const TrashCan& myCan ){
TrashCan other;
TrashCan empty;
empty.my_Contents = -1;

if ( empty.my_Contents < 0 ){
    throw logic_error("exception was caught.  moving on...");
}
else
{
other.my_Contents = combined.my_Contents - myCan.my_Contents;
return (other );
}
}

bool operator> ( const TrashCan& myCan, const TrashCan& yourCan) {                      /* MY bool override for the '< and > '  operators. */
TrashCan combined;
combined.my_Contents = yourCan.my_Contents + myCan.my_Contents ;

TrashCan empty;
empty.my_Empty = 0;


TrashCan other;
other.my_Contents = combined.my_Contents - myCan.my_Contents;


 return combined.my_Contents > other.my_Contents && myCan.my_Contents >     other.my_Contents; 



}

bool operator< (const TrashCan& myCan, const TrashCan& yourCan ) {          
TrashCan combined;
combined.my_Contents = yourCan.my_Contents + myCan.my_Contents ;

TrashCan other;
other.my_Contents = combined.my_Contents - myCan.my_Contents;

if (yourCan.my_Contents < myCan.my_Contents ){
    return yourCan.my_Contents > myCan.my_Contents ; }
else {
    return yourCan.my_Contents < myCan.my_Contents;
}





}


ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, TrashCan& myCan)
{
out <<myCan.my_Contents << " Contents in this trashcan";
return out;
}
```

======HEADER=========

```
#ifndef TRASHCAN_H
#define TRASHCAN_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class TrashCan {
public:
TrashCan( );
TrashCan( int size );
TrashCan( int size, int contents, int empty );

void setSize( int size );
int  getSize( );
int  getContents( );
void addItem( );
void empties( ); 
void cover( );
void uncover( );

friend TrashCan operator + ( const TrashCan& yourCan, const TrashCan& myCan );              /*as the assignment asks... I override the +,-, and <,> operators. */
friend TrashCan operator - ( const TrashCan& combined, const TrashCan& myCan);             /*I have used the bool statements for the <,> to compare sizes */
friend bool operator > ( const TrashCan& myCan,  const TrashCan& yourCan);
friend bool operator < ( const TrashCan& myCan, const TrashCan& yourCan );

friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, TrashCan& myCan);


void printCan( );

private:
bool myIsCovered;
int my_Size;
int my_Contents;
int my_Empty;
};



#endif
```

Comment: "Driver"? I don't see something remotely looking like a driver. And how about formatting your code *now* instead of in the next program, because it helps with finding errors?

Comment: And, did you use your debugger to find where it crashes?

Answer (score 1):

One issue is this:

```
void TrashCan::addItem() {
    my_Contents = my_Contents + 1;
    if (my_Contents > my_Size || my_Contents < my_Size) {
        throw logic_error("exception was caught.  moving on...");
    }
}
```

You are throwing a `logic_error` exception, but your `main` function doesn't catch the error.  Thus your program terminates.

I don't know the intent of this code, but if you were to simply run it, you would see that `my_Contents < my_Size` every time you call `add_Item`, thus causing the exception to be thrown.

Why not put a message to convince yourself that something is wrong?

```
void TrashCan::addItem() {
    my_Contents = my_Contents + 1;
    if (my_Contents > my_Size || my_Contents < my_Size) 
    {
        std::cout << "oh no, I'm about to die..." << std::endl;
        throw logic_error("exception was caught.  moving on...");
    }
}
```

Then your `main` function, if you don't want to end it on an unhandled exception, has to do a `try` / `catch`:

```
try { 
   yourCan.addItem();
}
catch(logic_error& e) { /* whatever */ }
```

Comment: The code was meant so the size of the trashcan isn't smaller than what is inside. (so no overflowing the trashcan) my exceptions seem to be the main problem as when I remove them, the program runs fine. The problem is that the purpose of this assignment is to practice exceptions so I'm trying my best to make it work. Thank you for the help by the way!